# JAXB treat List elements as its @XmlElements element

Tags: java, jaxb

I have something like:

```
class A {
    List<B> params;
    C other;
}

class B {
    @XmlElements(value = {
        @XmlElement(name="d",  type=D.class),
        @XmlElement(name="e",  type=E.class),
        @XmlElement(name="f",  type=F.class) })
    private Object param;
}
```

How should I change annotations to get serialization result like this:

```
<A>
  <params>
    <f>…</f>
    <d>…</d>
    <d>…</d>
    <e>…</e>
    <f>…</f>
    <d>…</d>
  </params>
  <other>…</other>
</A>
```

Comment: Is your `params` field supposed to be `List<C>` instead of `List<B>`?

Comment: What is the purpose of the `B` class.  Why not have `A` hold onto the list of `D`, `E`, and `F`?

Comment: @BlaiseDoughan It is supposed that `B` class will be used somewhere else. I am myself tend to eliminate `B` class, because I couldn't find solution, how to handle such a situation. In my case such a structure have to be serialized/deserialized to xml and to ASN.1 DER/BER. For ASN.1 serializer such case is in order of things, but for JAXB, as I see, it isn't so.